# "Followed by a second," or "followed by a second one?"

Tags: sentence

Erica lowered her pen to the blank page, wrote a verse, followed by a second (one).

In the example above, do I have to add that last **one**? Or just leave it as it is?

Comment: Related: "Which vs Which one" http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10084/99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but the style is a little strange. You might want to think about changing it to something like ‘. . . wrote a verse, and then another’.

Comment: Or if you want to emphasize the order of verses you could say "wrote a first verse, followed by a second."